# How to find Distinct No of Document on specific field MongoDB and print document count based on condition?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to get the distinct `categoryCode` and `categoryName` and print the count with this combination of how many documents are repeated. here is one condition with match operation gets all the documents based on `cat_type` , if cat_type does not exist then in category response count show as 0.
sample Data:

```
[
   {
      "cat_id":1,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_type":"A"
   },
   {
      "cat_id":2,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_type":"A"
   },
   {
      "cat_id":3,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode2",
      "categoryName":"categoryName2",
      "cat_type":"C"
   },
   {
      "cat_id":4,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode3",
      "categoryName":"categoryName3",
      "cat_type":"A"
   }
]
```

Expected Output: here match with `cat_type='A'`, category1 and category3 have `cat_type='A'` then count is print as normal but category2 does not have this `cat_type` then category2 also show in response with `cat_count=0`

```
[
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_count": 2
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode2",
      "categoryName":"categoryName2",
      "cat_count": 0
   },
   {
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode3",
      "categoryName":"categoryName3",
      "cat_count": 1
   }
]
```

I am using this query- https://mongoplayground.net/p/EasRK2xyLkG

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "cat_type": "A"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "categoryCode": "$categoryCode",
        "categoryName": "$categoryName"
      },
      "cat_count": {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "categoryCode": "$_id.categoryCode",
      "categoryName": "$_id.categoryName",
      "cat_count": "$cat_count"
    }
  }
])
```

with this query, 2nd category is not match so in response it it not showing.

Comment: I'm still confused as to what you want your output to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- remove `$match` stage
- check condition while sum, if `cat_type` is "A" then return 1 otherwise 0

```
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        "categoryCode": "$categoryCode",
        "categoryName": "$categoryName"
      },
      "cat_count": {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [{ $eq: ["$cat_type", "A"] }, 1, 0]
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vXhCicdpIDu)

Comment: db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "categoryCode": "$categoryCode",
        "categoryName": "$categoryName",
      },
      "catCount": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$eq": [
                "$cat.type", "A" ]
            },  "then": 1,
            "else": 0
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "categoryCode": "$_id.categoryCode",
      "categoryName": "$_id.categoryName",
      "catCount": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])

Comment: I am using this query because cat is an array and inside this array attribute in type have 'A' and checking condition with this but the array part with dot is not working and when I check outside the array then it work. how to fix this

Comment: orginal json look like this
[ { "cat_id":1, "categoryCode":"categoryCode1", "categoryName":"categoryName1", "cat":[{"type":"A"}] }, { "cat_id":2, "categoryCode":"categoryCode1", "categoryName":"categoryName1", "cat":[{"type":"A"}] }, { "cat_id":3, "categoryCode":"categoryCode2", "categoryName":"categoryName2", "cat":[{"type":"C"}] }, { "cat_id":4, "categoryCode":"categoryCode3", "categoryName":"categoryName3", "cat":[{"type":"A"}] } ]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69658059/how-to-find-count-based-on-condition-in-mongodb-aggregation