# How to search on dynamic field and sort best match result first in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have multiple documents and need to sort the document while sorting field name is unknown sort the document if input search field matches any of the document and sort based on the best result. and also searching input is not exact name it could be regex
Sample Data :

```
[
   {
      "cat_id":1,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_type":"A",
      "description":"Mens Upper Shirt"
   },
   {
      "cat_id":2,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode2",
      "categoryName":"categoryName2",
      "cat_type":"A",
      "description":"Shirt"
   },
   {
      "cat_id":3,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode3",
      "categoryName":"categoryName3",
      "cat_type":"Women Top wear",
      "description":"cloths"
   },
   {
      "cat_id":4,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode4",
      "categoryName":"categoryName4",
      "cat_type":"A",
      "description":"Women"
   }
]
```

if search='Shirt' then the response is:

```
[
   {
      "cat_id":2,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode2",
      "categoryName":"categoryName2",
      "cat_type":"A",
      "description":"Shirt"
   },
   {
      "cat_id":1,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode1",
      "categoryName":"categoryName1",
      "cat_type":"A",
      "description":"Mens Upper Shirt"
   }
]
```

if search='Women Top Wear' then response is :

```
[
   {
      "cat_id":3,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode3",
      "categoryName":"categoryName3",
      "cat_type":"Women Top wear",
      "description":"cloths"
   },
   {
      "cat_id":4,
      "categoryCode":"categoryCode4",
      "categoryName":"categoryName4",
      "cat_type":"A",
      "description":"Women"
   }
]
```

while any input you have to search it will check this value exist in all 5 attributes if exists then return that document and sort by best match

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong database for this, Mongo is not a search engine and thus using it for these needs will always have it's limits. I recommend you consider a more proper solution like [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/elastic-stack/) or [mongo atlas search](https://www.mongodb.com/atlas/search).

The biggest issue with using Mongo for this is your requirement of:

> sort by best match

What exactly defines a best match? the search engines i suggest have a built in scoring mechanism for such things. but if we're going to do it in Mongo you will have to define the logic yourself which is basically equal to building an entire scoring method for a database ( which if no simple task if you want it stable and successful ).

I will not bother with adding puesdo code to this as I suggest against doing this, but as you mentioned you basically have to do a regex search. once you matched the documents then just score calculations are left based on the logic you want to define for sorting the "best" match.